# Using Docker API to push to private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

What is the syntax to push an image to a private registry?

From the documentation, I would expect the below to work:

```
curl -X POST -i "http://localhost:2375/images/localhost:5000/oillio/my_app:1.0-SNAPSHOT/push"
```

I can use the CLI to do this:

```
docker push localhost:5000/oillio/my_app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

This works fine.  But I can't figure out what the syntax is to do this from the API.  When I try the above, I get a status 500 response with the text "EOF"

Comment: im still getting EOF ,does it work for you ?I got a "EOF" when I did a     curl -X POST -H 'X-Registry-Auth' http://localhost:4243/images/localhost:5000/test/push/(slash at end) , I got a "404 page not found" when I did a     curl -X POST -H 'X-Registry-Auth' http://localhost:4243/images/localhost:5000/test/push/.  My docker has the following images     REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
    localhost:5000/test     latest              98adsfasd        1 hours ago                  111 MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag needs to be as a parameter and not within the url:

`/images/<imageName>/push?tag=<tadName>`

Note that you will also need the `X-Registry-Auth` header.

Answer (score -1):

a working example:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Registry-Auth:787f5fe5195c40ef924ac8d67948e15a" http://172.19.32.116:8833/images/172.19.32.116:5000/test7/push
```