# What is content of X-Registry-Auth for Docker push to private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

What should the content of the X-Registry-Auth header be when pushing a Docker image to a private registry using the [REST API](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.14/#push-an-image-on-the-registry)?  Per [Using Docker API to push to private registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296830/using-docker-api-to-push-to-private-registry/24305408#24305408), an X-Registry-Auth header is required. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/vXcA8fsCNZM suggests that the value should be a base64 encoded JSON string of the form:

```
{'username': string, 'password': string, 'email': string, 'serveraddress' : string}
```

After setting suitable environment variables, I did:

```
XRA=`echo "{\"username\": \"${USERNAME}\", \"password\": \"${PASSWORD}\", \"email\": \"${EMAIL_ADDRESS}\", \"serveraddress\" : \"${SERVER_ADDRESS}\"}" | base64 --wrap=0`
curl  -v --request POST --header "X-Registry-Auth: $XRA" http://$DOCKER_HOST/v1/images/$REGISTRY/$NAMESPACE/$REPOSITORY?tag=$TAG
```

And get a `403 Forbidden` response.

Perhaps the problem is just that I don't know what the values should be. How can I determine them?  Docker seems to have a way; `sudo docker push $REGISTRY/$NAMESPACE/$REPOSITORY:$TAG` works just fine.

Comment: I was able to push to my Docker Hub account using this. However, it seems to work better (for me at least) if an image has already been pushed first using `docker login` and `docker push`.

Comment: Your solution works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had a private nexus docker repo (Docker Api v2), and for me, that was the solution:

```
 XRA=`echo "{ \"username\": \"yourname\", \"password\": \"yourpass\", \"email\": \"youmail@example.org\" }" | base64 --wrap=0`
 curl  -X POST  -d "" -H "X-Registry-Auth: $XRA" http://localhost:4243/images/create?fromImage=private.host:19003/imagename&tag=latest
```

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me in node.js (after hours of frustrating trials...):

```
var authInfo2 = `{\"username\": \"${user}\", \"password\": \"${passwd}\", \"email\": \"${email}\", \"serveraddress\": \"${registry}\"}`

var authInfo = Buffer.from(authInfo2).toString('base64')

var result = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Registry-Auth' : authInfo }
})
```

Comment: Anything related with Docker API is hours of frustrating trials, my workload is a feature a day. Too slow, too frustrating. Just sharing coding pains here hahha. Have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing two layers in your encoding.  The actual code that generates the header (from [github](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/auth/auth.py))

```
def encode_header(auth):
    auth_json = json.dumps(auth).encode('ascii')
    return base64.b64encode(auth_json)

def encode_full_header(auth):
    """ Returns the given auth block encoded for the X-Registry-Config header.
    """
    return encode_header({'configs': auth})
```

So you need an outer map of { 'configs': [ array of auth entries ] }, all json-then-base64 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

To check your authentication environment variables issue

```
docker login --username $USERNAME --password $PASSWORD --email $EMAIL_ADDRESS $SERVER_ADDRESS
```

If they are correct you'll see "Login Succeeded".

I suspect $NAMESPACE should match $USERNAME.
Try using v1.13 as the version instead of v1.